# Code First add database in App_Data folder (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to add database in App_Data folder in my application.

This is my connection string in `Web.config` file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestTask-20151223145656;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\TestTaskDb.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And this is my `TestTaskDb` class

```
public class TestTaskDb : DbContext
{
    public TestTaskDb() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Vacancy> Vacancies { get; set; }
}
```

As I can see there is `TestTaskDb.mdf` in my `App_Data` folder

[image]

But I'm not sure, if I send my project to other person, and he open it on his computer, build and run application, would it work with my database and its data or not?

Comment: A `.mdf` file is a **SQL Server** database file - to do anything with it, that other person must also have some **SQL Server** instance (Express or higher - **NOT** SQL Server Compact / CE!) installed to make use of that database file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm not sure, if I send my project to other person, and he open it
>   on his computer, build and run application, would it work with my
>   database and its data or not?

That will depend on whether you send him the contents of the `App_Data` folder. So basically if you want him to use your database then make sure you have sent the proper `mdf` and `ldf` files to him.

Comment: So if I send him my project with all folders and files which it contains, it will work on his computer and shows all data from database when he run it on his computer from VS?

Comment: Yeap, that's the point of an embedded database. You don't need a centralized server for it. Of course you should never use anything like that in a production because this can't scale.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Actually it's my test task to get a job but I'm studing and I have a little expierence, so I'm not sure about these things.